# Will renaming a file change its CRC?

Tags: crc

As stated, will renaming a file change the CRC? I've checked in plain text files and it didn't.  Does this apply to all files of all formats?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CRC is calculated on the contents of the file.  The file name is just an entry in the file system that allows access to the file.  It's not part of the file itself, so it's not part of the CRC.

Answer (score 4):

CRC is normally calculated on file content, but there's no prison sentence prescribed for writing a CRC utility that includes the filename.  Check your particular utility's documentation, or I'd say it's safe to trust the results implied by your experiment.